# Flutter contacts_service package use

Tags: loops, flutter, contacts

I am using https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service.
I am able to do:

```
contacts.forEach((contact){
      print(contact.displayName);
});
```

How do I print items of contact.emails ?
They are defined as Iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
contacts.forEach((contact) {
  print(contact.displayName);
  contact.emails.forEach((item) {
    print(item.value);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Emails are stored in a label: value format in that lib. This should work:

```dart
      contacts.forEach((contact) {
        print('Name: ${contact.displayName}');
        for (var email in contact.emails) {
          print('Email: ${email.label} => ${email.value}');
        }
      });
```